# How to scroll in the Android App using appium+Java?

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I need to scroll vertically (up and down) and horizontally (left and right) using appium + selenium + java. Can anyone please help me with snippet of the code required for this with explanation so I can use it further in other projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To **Swipe right to left** use below code

```
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();            
int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.8);          
int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.20);       
int starty = size.height / 2;   
driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 1000);
```

**left to right** : the direction simply change start-x to end-x and end-x to startx

**To swipe up/down** : x-axis co-ordinates will remain same only y-coordinates will change.

If you are curious to know more about co-ordinates then turn on "*Pointer location*" setting from "*Developer options*" and observe co-ordinates manually.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I will try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void swipe(MobileDriver driver, DIRECTION direction, long duration) {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    int startX = 0;
    int endX = 0;
    int startY = 0;
    int endY = 0;

    switch (direction){
        case RIGHT:
            startY = (int) (size.height /2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            break;

        case LEFT:
            startY = (int) (size.height /2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            break;

        case UP:
            endY= (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            startY  = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);
            break;


        case DOWN:
            startY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            endY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);

            break;

    }

    new TouchAction(driver)
            .press(startX, startY)
            .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
            .moveTo(endX, startY)
            .release()
            .perform();

}
```

Here is sample code for swiping in all directions. Just provide direction and duration of swipe.

Code is proven good.